# Embedding a calendar web app (which accesses google calendar) in my homepage

Tags: iframe, google-calendar

I have made my own calendar web app using flask and it runs on pythonanywhere.com. The app reads and writes data using the google calendar API. The app has been working perfectly for years.

The homepage I use in my browser is actually my own local .html file which contains my own favourite links etc. Using this local file has also been working fine for years.

What I would really like now is to be able to view them both at the same time. The obvious thing to do is to include my calendar app in an iframe within my homepage with something like

```
<iframe src="https://mywebapp.pythonanywhere.com"></iframe>
```

but when I try this, the iframe box contains:

```
mywebapp.pythonanywhere.com redirected you too many times
```

I have googled the error "redirected you too many times" but there seem to be so many possible causes and solutions (some of which I scarcely understand) that I don't know where to begin and I'm hoping that having described my particular circumstances might reveal an obvious answer.

I know there are many possible alternatives to iframe - might a different method make it less likely that I get this kind of error?... or make the error easier to diagnose?

**EDIT:** The error message reported was from Chrome but I just tested with Edge and got a deferent message: "`accounts.google.com refused to connect.`"

**EDIT:** In response to Stephen Ostermiller's suggestion I looked at Chrome's console tab and saw "`Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`" - not sure what it means yet but I'm looking into it now...

**EDIT:** Seems it's related to "`x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN`" - I'm guessing that somehow google is detecting that I'm trying to access the API from two different places, my homepage and pythonanywhere.com and it thinks this is a security problem and so is refusing to play ball. BTW, if I just put a google calendar (not wrapped in my pythonanywhere app) in the iframe then I can see the calendar without a problem... So is this the end of the road? Am I trying to do the impossible?

Comment: Can you provide more debugging details?  What browser are you using?  Have you tried multiple browsers?   What do you see when you look in the developer tools for your browser, especially the console and network tabs?

Comment: The site owner doesn't want that URL iframed. That's what it means.